# R - Change the order of characters in a list

Tags: r, string, list

Hello i have this list

```
    LIST<-list(list("DC,MD,MA,Washigton,Baltimore,Boston,France,Turkey,China"),
           list("DC,MD,Washington,Baltimore,France,Turkey"),
           list("DC,Washington,France,Turkey,China")
```

I want to change the order of the strings of the sublists according to this logic:

```
    LIST<-list(list("DC,Washington,MD,Baltimore,MA,Boston,France,Turkey,China"),
               list("x1,y1,x2,y2,z1,z2,z3"),
               list("x1,y1,z1,z2,z3"))
```

Note that  x and y have the same count and can be up to 3. Z do not have count restriction. I do not want of course the change the order manually for each sublist but with an automated way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(magrittr)
fun=function(string){
 lapply(strsplit(string,","),function(x)sub("([a-z])([0-9])","\\2\\1",x)%>%
    sort()%>%sub("([0-9])([a-z])","\\2\\1",.)%>%paste(collapse=","))
}

rapply(LIST,fun,how="list")
```

After edition:

```
 fun=function(string,NO){
  lapply(strsplit(string,","),function(x) 
    paste(c(by(x, c(s<-rep(1:NO,2),rep(0,length(x)-length(s)))
               ,paste0,collapse=",")),collapse=", "))
}
rapply(LIST,fun,how="list",NO=3)
```

Comment: Actually this one is more accurate: LIST<-list(list("DC,MD,MA,Baltimore,Washington,Boston,France,China"),
       list("DC,MD,MA,Baltimore,Washington,Boston,France,China,Turkey")) x represents states, y cities and z irrelevant countries. z do not need to match with the others

Comment: What do you need from it? How do you want it arranged?

Comment: State should be near to its city

Comment: Am sorry I don't know the states and cities of America.. You must provide an objective way for one to translate that into a code. How many states How many cities?

Comment: The relation between them is like my initial post: if x1,x2,x3 are the states then the correspondent cities are y1,y2,y3. There can be from 1 to 3 x and y and there are always as many x as y

Comment: Should I add another answer here or would you mind asking another question then I post the answer? This answer I gave specifically answers the question ask. If you don't mind, you might ask that other question and I will post the answer

Comment: i editted the question so you can post here the answer

Comment: except if you want me to accept this answer and begin a new topic.

Comment: I have added both. Well that would be great but as you can see, both solutions have been added

Comment: tnx can you explain me this line?paste(c(by(x, c(rep(1:3,2),rep(3,length(x)-6))

Comment: The `c(rep(1:3,2),rep(4,length(x)-6)` simply creates a vector 1,2,3,1,2,3,4,4 if x is of length 8 or 1,2,3,1,2,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4 if the length is 15. I only need the first 6. The rest are grouped together. In those first six, collect the ones together, the twos together, etc etc... then paste them together

Comment: I see..clever! but for some reason it cannot be applied here [[1]]
[1] "MA, WA, Boston, Seattle, France"

Comment: I wrote that in a specific code. Let me edit it for generality ie change the 3 into 2 and also the 2 into 1 I will edit the code for you

Comment: Just NO means number of cities. So if you have 3 you will input 3 etc etc

Comment: I hope it now works. There was a six hat i had left in the code

Comment: it is working `fun("MA, WA, Boston, Seattle, France",2)
[[1]]
[1] " France , MA, Boston ,  WA, Seattle"`

Comment: Hi Onyambu, suppose that it is fun("MA", "WA", "Boston", "Seattle", "France",2) which means that the sublists include separated characters not one character. How could it work? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How can I display city before state?